# Mongoose and typescript how can i update the data?

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I have an interface like this.

```
export interface IMerchant{
    id?:string,
    name:string,
    surname:string,
    mail:string,
}
```

My schema like this

```
    import { Schema, model, Model } from 'mongoose';

    interface IMerchantModel extends Model<IMerchant> {
        getAllMerchants(): IMerchant[];
        setMerchant(merchant:IMerchant):IMerchant;
    }
    
    const merchantSchema = new Schema<IMerchant, IMerchantModel>({
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        surname:{type:String,required:true},
        mail:{type:String,required:true},
    },
    {
        timestamps: { createdAt: "createdDate", updatedAt: "updatedDate" },
        toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    });

    const Merchant = model<IMerchant, IMerchantModel>('Merchant', merchantSchema);
    export default Merchant;
```

My main goal is create a data if not exist or update it if exist.

```
merchantSchema.static('setMerchant', async function setMerchant(merchant:IMerchant) {
    try{
        if(merchant.id){
            // if object has id field get from collection.
            let m = await this.findOne({ id: merchant.id }) as IMerchant;
            if (m) {
               m={...merchant};
               m.save();
               //Error -> Property 'save' does not exist on type 'IMerchant'.
            }
            return m;
        }
        else{
            // if not exist, create one
            const newData= new Merchant(merchant);
            const savedData=await newData.save();
            return savedData;
        }
    }
    catch(e){
        // throw an Error
    }
});
```

So main problem in update I got an error.

> Property 'save' does not exist on type 'IMerchant'.

How can I cast return data from findOne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [this documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html#using-extends-document) mongoose doesn't suggest extends Document.

> Alternatively, your document interface can extend Mongoose's Document
> class.
>
> We strongly recommend against using this approach, its support will be
> dropped in the next major version as it causes major performance
> issues. Many Mongoose TypeScript codebases use the below approach.
>
> ```
> import { Document, Schema, model, connect } from 'mongoose';
>
> interface IUser extends Document {
>   name: string;
>   email: string;
>   avatar?: string;
> }
> ```

Thus, HydratedDocument can be solution.

```
import { Schema, model, Model, HydratedDocument } from 'mongoose';
```

change from

```
let m = await this.findOne({ id: merchant.id }) as IMerchant;
```

to

```
let m = await this.findOne({ id: merchant.id }) as HydratedDocument<IMerchant>;
```